# Android setImageResources

Tags: android

I'm making an android application in which the user must guess the people in photo, but I have a problem.
I have an ImageView and I want that when the user guesses or not some people, the image changes.
I'm using the setImageResources() method but it's not working correctly.

```
public void checkAnswer(){

    imageGuess.setImageResource(R.drawable.luizao);

    if (answer2.isChecked()){
        countRightAnswers++;
        marks_number.setText(countRightAnswers.toString());
        imageGuess.setImageResource(R.drawable.ruben_pintu);
    } else {
        imageGuess.setImageResource(R.drawable.ruben_pintu);
    }

    if (answer4.isChecked()){
        countRightAnswers++;
        marks_number.setText(countRightAnswers.toString());
        imageGuess.setImageResource(R.drawable.ruben_cani);
    } else {
        imageGuess.setImageResource(R.drawable.ruben_cani);
    }

}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: answer2.isChecked() or not -  you are using the same image

Comment: With your code, your imageGuess always displays the ruben_cani ressource, because it doesn't depend on which answer is checked or not. (You set the ImageRessource with the same ressource in the "if" part and in the "else" part).

Comment: ... and so for ruben_pintu.

Comment: maybe you can fix your logic or you can give more explanation ;)